# Justifying text in table

Tags: tabularx

Could you kindly help me to justify text in the table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}LLc@{}}
        \toprule
\thead{Known facts}
    &   \thead{Open questions}
        &   \thead{Objectives}   \\
        \midrule
Ply-strength depends on ply-thickness (also known as in-situ effect)
    &   There is no evidence of the in-situ effect under transverse shear
        & \multirow{10}{*}{1} \\
    &  There is controversy about which damage mechanism triggers the other
        &  \\
Out-of-plane loads induce  shear cracks and delaminations
    &   There is controversy about which damage  mechanism   penalizes  the components' load-carrying capacity  &  \\
        &   There is no clear evidence of how ply-thickness affects damage sequence evolution              &  \\
    \midrule
Thin-plies increase several in-plane mechanical properties  because of the in-situ effect
    & \multirow{5}{=}{There is little information on how ply-thickness affects thin laminates' impact response}
        & \multirow{5}{*}{2}                \\
Thin-plies display brittle failure mechanisms
    &   &                                   \\
    \midrule
Interleaving polyamide veils with a relatively high fibre areal weight enhances impact resistance, tolerance and interlaminar fracture toughness

\smallskip
The improvement comes with a penalty of tensile and compressive properties
    &   Few studies incorporate veils with low fibre areal weight

        \smallskip
        No study toughens thin-ply laminates

        \smallskip
        Few studies connect veil fibre architecture and mechanical properties
        & \multirow{6}{*}{3$\&$4} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Eliminating the phrase `>{\RaggedRight}` from the `L`-column definition would go a long way.

Comment: Just change `{@{}LLc@{}}` to `{@{}XXc@{}}`. The `X` column type typesets its material fully justified, whereas the `L` column type is designed to typeset its material "raggedright" -- aka "flushleft". That said, tabular material in narrow columns often looks much better if it's typeset raggedright.